# Find all incongruent solutions to this equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find all incongruent solutions to $$11x^{33} \equiv 2 \pmod{17} $$

Comment: Your Question would be improved by explaining what you mean by "incongruent" solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{16}\equiv1 \pmod {17}$ by Fermat's little theorem. (unless $x$ is a multiple of $17$, but this case obviously doesn't generate solutions to the problem at hand).

So
$11x^{33}\equiv11x \equiv2\pmod {17}$

$x\equiv\frac{2}{11}\equiv\frac{2}{-6}\equiv-\frac 13 \equiv \frac{33}{3}\equiv11 \pmod {17}$

So the solutions are $x=11+17k$

Comment: Please don't provide complete solutions for people who have shown zero work/effort of their own.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
11a\equiv 1 \mod 17 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \equiv 14 \mod 17
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
x^{33}\equiv 11 \mod 17.
\end{align}
Using Euler's theorem, we have that
\begin{align}
x^{33}\equiv  x \equiv 11 \mod 17.
\end{align}